# Kivy - Labels are sometimes (randomly) not added to canvas

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to add some labels to a kivy app using "with canvas". The labels are supposed to appear after pressing a button, but sometimes only some of them appear and only after I press the button several times, I get all of them.

this is the button callback:

```py
def calculateCallback(self, instance):

    global currentState

    if currentState == 'drawRooms':
        self.reArrangeGraph()
    elif currentState == 'getBubbles':
        self.reArrangeGraph()
        self.dboard.drawBubbles()
    elif currentState == 'drawPlan':
        self.dboard.drawGrid()
    elif currentState == 'finishedPlan':
        self.dboard.canvas.clear()
        for key, node in self.dboard.nodes.items():
            print("type is: ", node.getType())
            with self.canvas:
                Label(pos=node.pos, text=node.getType())
```

The state is `finishedPlan`, and I expect to see on the screen all the labels. I get the "type is:" printouts correctly for all the labels, but not all labels are printed to the screen.

Any ideas..?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`canvas`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html) is the root object used for drawing e.g. rectangle, circle, ellipse, line, etc. To add widgets to a layout use `self.add_widget(Label(...))`

Replace

```
    with self.canvas:
        Label(pos=node.pos, text=node.getType())
```

with

```
    self.add_widget(Label(pos=node.pos, text=node.getType()))
```